# Struts 1.1 + Hibernate 3.2 Integration

Tags: java, hibernate, struts-1, dom4j, ejb-2.x

I am trying to integrate hibernate into an existing struts + ejb 2.0 application. I had to write a struts-hibernate plugin for the session creation from hibernate.cfg.xml. I also created model and hbm files, but I am unable to bring up the application due to the jar files conflict, I guess. I keep getting this exception:

```
[11/8/10 10:58:59:257 EST] 00000023 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet action: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.dom4j.io.OutputFormat
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:59)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:120)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:212)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:197)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:201)
 at com.vo.common.struts.utils.HibernatePlugIn.init(HibernatePlugIn.java:47)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:185)
 at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:316)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1119)
 at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:149)
```

Comment: Prashanth Muthyala, are you trying to have a conversation with others in your answers?  StackOverflow is not designed to be used this way. An answer is supposed to answer the original question.  Use the "Add comments" to have a dialog with others.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have dom4j on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your web project, there is no dom4j-1.6.1.jar inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Place the jar there, rebuild your project (I'm assuming EAR file) and redeploy it to WAS (if I'm correct).

Having the dom.jar in your classpath helps only Eclipse in managing classpaths of class files when doing development but building your JAR/WAR/EAR files, you have to manage your libraries (which you can configure in Eclipse too).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it, the problem was with classpath, but not the web-inf/lib, but server class path where in the server.xml also need to have the set of jars that are needed by the application.

Thank you very much.